# Determine solutions for $\tan{x}\cos^{2}{x}-\tan{x}=0$ in the interval $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$.

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble simplifying the function in order to determine the solutions. I have tried a few methods but I remain stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I read it right it factors as $(\tan x)(\cos^2 x-1)$.

Comment: @André Nicolas Do I have to simplify it any further to find the solutions?

Comment: No further simplification needed.

Comment: @Gabriel: You need to know that a product is zero if and only if at least one of the factors is.

Comment: Okay so then that would mean the solutions include, 0,-2pi,-pi, pi, 2pi

Comment: And that's all. For $\tan x=0$ at these places, and nowhere else. And $\cos^2 x-1=0$ adds no new solutions.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write your equation in the form $$\tan(x)(\cos(x)-1)(\cos(x)+1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT (filter the ones you need):

Assuming $\cos(x)\ne 0$:

$$\tan(x)\cos^2(x)-\tan(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)\sin(x)-\tan(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)\left(\cos(x)-\sec(x)\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space\cos(x)-\sec(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space\sec(x)(\cos(x)-1)(1+\cos(x))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $y=\cos(x)$:

---

$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space y-\frac{1}{y}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space \frac{y^2-1}{y}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space y^2-1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space (y-1)(y+1)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space y-1=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space y+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space y=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space y=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space \cos(x)=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space \cos(x)=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\pi n_1\space\space\vee\space\space x=2\pi n_2\space\space\vee\space\space x=\pi+2\pi n_3$$